# Search ranks accessories higher than actual products in sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

In sphinx, search ranks accessories higher than actual products.

For e.g. if I search for `iPhone`, I would get `iPhone cases`, `batteries` etc. on top and actual iPhone products below it.

This is my search query:

```
SELECT ID FROM idx_product_title WHERE MATCH('iphone') LIMIT 0,10
```

Any hint on how I can rank the actual products higher?

Comment: can you check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120581/sphinx-search-ranking-broken ?

Comment: that does give a hint but not a solution, will search more on how to rank relevant results higher

Comment: Well in part it depends your index is actually setup. Do have some flag in the database that flags if a product is an 'accessory' for another item? Also do you want tems to EXPLICITLY always show first, or just MORE LIKELY to show near top? Similar results, but very different implementation

Comment: @barryhunter this is a good idea to have a flag in database that tells if this product is an accessory to another... but unfortunately our database does not have this flag... actually when someone is searching for `iphone` then it means they are looking for the phone itself and not its case or battery... if someone wants battery, they would search `iphone battery`... so it makes more sense to only show the actual product explicitly...

Comment: I think a better way is to have a small collection of keywords like `case`, `battery`, `accessory`, etc and then have all search calls omit these keywords from the search call... and only if any of these keywords exist in user search keywords, then skip them from the omit keywords clause... how is that idea guys..?